# Integration between MS Exchange and Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex

Is it possible to build Flex application to send and receive email to and from Ms Exchange which I am building my CMS platform? Coldfusion does it but do anyone have suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If you can create COM objects with Flex then you can use a library such as Outlook Rememption http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/, which has Exchange support. I'm using this in a project at the moment and its working very well.

Exchange also offers several other API's amongst which is A web-services API and WebDav with which you should be able to integrate. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204073%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

Comment: So you does it within the browser?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with Javascript (http://outatime.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/javascript-webdav-client/) and I can't imagine that Flex won't give you that functionality. Perhaps look here: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Synchronous_data_calling_with_Flex-7184.html